# Django model field default based on another model field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use Django Admin to build a management site. There are two tables, one is `ModelA` with data in it, another is `ModelB` with nothing in it. If one model field `b_b` in `ModelB` is None, it can be displayed on the webpage with the value of `ModelA`'s field `a_b`.

I don't know how to do it, Here is the pseudo code:

In models.py

```
from django.db import models

class ModelA(models.Model):
  a_a = models.CharField(max_length=6)
  a_b = models.CharField(max_length=6)

class ModelB(models.Model):
  modela = models.OneToOneField(ModelA)
  b_b = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=[(1, 'M'), (2, 'F')], default=self.modela.a_b)
```

In admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ModelA, ModelB

class ModelBAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fields = ['b_b']
  list_display = ('b_b')
```

I think if b_b of modelB have default value of relative a_b value of modelA, I have a default value of b_b(View) in the django admin change(edit) page which associate data to a particular modelB instance.

I want to fill b_b in web page more easily.

I don't know whether this requirement can be achieved? Or there is another way can achieve this?

I try to custom the templates filter as following:

In templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html

```
 {% load drop_null %}

    {% if field.is_checkbox %}
        {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
    {% else %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {% if field.is_readonly %}
            <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
        {% else %}
            {% if field.field.name == 'b_b' %}
                {{ field|dropnull }}
            {% else %}
                {{ field.field }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```

In templatetags/drop_null.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='dropnull')
def dropnull(cls):
    return cls.modela.a_b
```

The 'field' is < django.contrib.admin.helpers.AdminField object at 0x3cc3550> . It is not an instance of ModelB.
How can I get ModelB instance?

Comment: I think you really need to reevaluate what you are trying to acheive here. Will ModelA only have one row of data? Also self.modela wont work as "self" is the instance of ModelB.

Comment: When you say "it can be displayed on the webpage with…" which web page are you referring to? The admin form to create a new `modelB` instance or the public page where visitor will see data associated to a particular `modelB` instance?

Comment: I write a pseudo code that can not execute. I want ModelB.b_b have a default to display on admin page where admin visitor will see data associated to a particular modelB instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `save` method of your `modelB` model instead of providing a default value:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela = models.OneToOneField(ModelA)
    b_b = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=[(1, 'M'), (2, 'F')], blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.b_b:
            self.b_b = self.modela.a_b
        super(ModelB, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

### Edit after clarification in the comments

If you just want to display the value to visitors but want to keep the fact that the `ModelB.b_b` is empty, the logic should lay in the template.

Assuming your view set `objB` in the context being the `ModelB` object your are interested to display, the relevant part of the template should look like:

```
{% with objB.b_b as bValue %}
{% if not bValue %}
    <p>{{ objB.modela.a_b }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p>{{ bValue }}</p>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Does this save method override ModelB instance's save action?  I don't need to save, I just need to display a default in ModelB instance in view page. I want easily fill b_b

Comment: I think your idea of modify the template is right. I found django admin template's path is /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html. Should I try to modify this abstract file?

Comment: As you are adding comments, I am more and more confused about what you are trying to achieve. You said you wanted the value substitution on "the public page where visitor will see data associated to a particular modelB instance" and here you are talking about admin template. That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, there was some misunderstanding in my mind. I mean the admin pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can define and register one custom `template filter` for  admin templates

From the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: The 'field' in fieldset.html is <django.contrib.admin.helpers.AdminField object at 0x3cc3550>. It is not an instance of ModelB.
How can I get ModelB instance? The detail I added to the original question I asked.