# Django concurrent get-and-increment

Tags: python, django, transactions

Lets say I have a model ***A*** which has an ***account_number*** field and when a new instance of ***A*** is created a ***counter*** field in my model ***B*** increments it's value by one. This value will be the same that my ***account_number*** field will receive.

I want to protect the operation from concurrent modifications so that my ***account_number*** is always the correct one.

I want to do something like the following:

```
instance.account_number = F('modelB_table.counter') + 1
```

also updating the ***counter*** value in ***B***

**How can I achieve this in Django 1.9?**

**Could transactions be helpful in this case?**

Comment: maybe use double-underscore syntax like everywhere else in Django ORM `F('modelB_table__counter')`

Comment: @Anentropic but that would just set the ***account_number*** in instance, not update the counter in ***B***

Comment: Looks like that's some kind of duplicate question see [Django model field default based on another model field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293204/django-model-field-default-based-on-another-model-field) question.

Comment: @Andriy This is not a duplicate of that questions, I'm asking for concurrent control techniques

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this in Django using transactions. You'd do something like:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    ModelB.objects.update(counter=F('counter') + 1)
    new_counter = ModelB.objects.get().counter
    a_instance.account_number = new_counter
    a_instance.save()
```

This needs to be done at a transaction isolation level of `READ_COMMITTED` or above. (In PostgreSQL the default isolation level is `READ_COMMITTED`, I'm not sure about other databases.)

It works because that isolation level makes *dirty reads* impossible, so there's no way for a concurrent transaction to update the counter until the other commits.